# Subsite creation issue

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, deployment, sub-site

I created a site in french. Then I've created a subsite to this site (also in french), I saved this subsite as a template. Later I deployed my site on another web application and I applied an english language pack. My problem: when I'm on my english site I can't create a subsite from my template.
So do you think this is a language problem or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the Site template before the Applying the English Language pack then it should be a problem.

Because when you save the site as template it bundle everything which is part of sites and at that time English was not present so no reference for English.I am sure you getting some mismatch error.

easy test is create a new template and try it

Comment: You were right, thanks.
To solve my problem I've deployed my site and my subsite on the english web application and then I saved my subsite as a template.
Now the only problem is that every time I create a subsite from the template I have to manually change the language settings to set my subsite in english.
Do you know how to set english as a default language?
Thanks again!